# Running a program logic within a program

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, libgdx

Note: This thread is not about launching a compiled program from within another program. But rather about running another program logic in parallel to the main program.

---

In libGDX, a game is handled with screen. A screen has a specific kind of display and input. For example: Menu Screen, Game Screen and option screen.

In most basic game switching game screen is not really a problem.  You know that from menu you can go to game or option and you know that when you finish option and game, you get back to menu. So you can actually hard code the destination screen in those class, it's like a "Goto Menu Screen".

One of my screen will be composed of sub-screen which is the same logic as screen except that it stacks multiple sub-screen displayed when that screen is active. Now I am trying to make some sort of hybrid video/board game engine. One of the sub screen could be "Chose a card from your hand", now in that case, there could be multiple situations where a card could be played from your hand. Which mean that when the card is chosen you actually don't know where to go next. For example, let's take that turn order sequence:

- Draw a card
- Play a card from your hand
- Place that card into play
- Play a card from your hand
- Place that card in the discard pile

Now, you want to reuse the code of "play a card from your hand" to make sure you do not code the same thing twice. But here, "Play a card from your hand" don't know if it should next play the selected card into play or place the selected card into the discard pile. So it cannot use the "GoTo" method.

In fact I will need to have some sort of "Program" to change screen that would map the procedure of the game play. The game would first draw a card, then as the player to chose a card, then use the return value and place that card into play, etc. That works well in a regular program, but that seems harder to do in Libgdx, because the framework is real time. So after each executed command, I need to return the handle of the program to libgdx so that he can do proper animations and rendering. Else the program will simply freeze and wait for user input which will never work. So I need to run a program in parallel of the libgdx program that will tell libgdx which sub-screen to display according to the logic of the game.

So far, I found 2 solutions, but I was wondering if there was something else that I could use.

The first un-elegant solution is an instruction pointer. Like the processor is doing in assembly, remember the ID of the next instruction to run, have a huge switch case that will list all possible instruction. Each time render is called, it will check if the subscreen is finished, if yes, it will execute the next instruction. It could look to something like this:

Note: the code is not perfect, it's just for the illustration.

```
static int IP = 1; // instruction pointer

if ( subscreen_finished == true )
   switch ( IP )
   {
      case 1:
         hand.draw_card();
         IP = 2;
      break; 
      case 2:
         hand.chose_card();
         IP = 3;
      break;
      case 3:
         play_card ( hand.getcard());
         IP = 4;
      break;
      case 4:
         hand.chose_card();
         IP=5;
      break;
      case 5:
         hand.discard ( hand.getcard() );
         IP=6
      break;
      case 6:
         end_of_turn();
      break;
   }
```

Each function call would set subscreen_finished to false. It basically wait for the user input, or wait for the animation to be completed before setting it to true.

As you can see, it's really not elegant and it could be very hard to follow the program especially if you want loops like " do 3 actions".

The second method consist in running a parallel thread that could work like this

```
hand.draw_card();
hand.chose_card();
hand.play_card ( hand.getcard );
hand.chose_card();
hand.discard ( hand.getcard );
end_of_turn();
```

Each function call would setup the right subscreen and enter a waiting loop until an answer is chosen by the player or the animations are completed. Looks much more elegant, but I must use multi-threading.

On another thread somebody suggested using state machine and messaging.

But the state machine does not quite work for me. Because in my example above, if the game is at the "chose a card from hand" state, in order to know which state to do next, it needs to know all the previous steps that were accomplished. Or know that we are at step 4 and that the next step is 5 because "chose card" could be called at step 2 or 4.

Is there any other solution available? It's really hard to find documentation or other implementation of something similar, because most application are not real time like it's the case of video games.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with multithreading or parallel processing. Anyway, what if you keep a stack (list) of events where each event can have its own state machine and send a return value to the previous event when it pops itself?

Comment: My second solution was to run a parallel thread that setup the next step and wait until it's completed.

Comment: Ok so what you are basically saying is populate all the steps of a turn in a list, use an iterator (like if it was an instruction pointer) with maybe repeating steps that are in loop. The only issue I can see is if step are conditional to previous step outcome. In that case, I won't be able to do so.

Comment: Well each step in the list could pass info to the next step, and then await info to be passed back. Kind of like the task stack in Android, if you're familiar with that.